# How to cleanly print a message in a bash shell after a background process finishes?

Tags: bash

I want to start a lengthy process in the background in my bash shell, get notified when that process is finished, and then be returned to the command line in elegant fashion. Here's what I have so far:

```
echo $(lengthy_process >/dev/null 2&>1 ; printf "consummatum est.\r" ) &
```

This almost works. The message "consummatum est" eventually shows, but it leaves my command prompt in an ugly/indeterminate state with the text interjected into what I happen to be typing.

Is there a way to get the background process to print to terminal without interrupting what I'm doing and without requiring a carriage return to get the command prompt into a fresh state?

Comment: Bash does this automatically, no? When a background process finishes, the next time the prompt gets updated, it prints `[1]+  Done  (command)`

Comment: @wjandrea. Sort of, yeah. I just realized that what's happening is that the command prompt is still there and active on my above approach, but it's being printed over by the final echo. So now I'm trying to figure out if I can orchestrate some sort of "Done. Press X to continue" sequence where I then clear that message so you can see the prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

a more modern take with notify-send

```
( lengthy_process &>/dev/null; notify-send "done" ) &
```

otherwise you're asking for the interruption.  You may want to display exit status as well.

Comment: What package is this from?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I think this only works with a desktop environment. I'm writing a script for shell-only usage on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script like this (`show-msg`) that saves the cursor position, prints the message and restores the cursor position after.

```
#! /bin/bash

tput sc; tput cup 0 0
printf '%s
================
PROCESS FINISHED
================
%s\n' "$(tput setab 13)" "$(tput sgr0)"
tput rc
```

and then

```
( lengthy_process &>/dev/null; ./show-msg ) &
```

which will show the message without interfering with your typing.

Comment: This seems to just print the message to the top of my screen. Does my terminal need some special setting? I like that it doesn't interfere with whatever is being written at the live command prompt (unless that's at the top of the screen).

Answer (score 0):

I realized the command prompt in the main shell was still active when the final echo prints its message, but it was printing over the prompt and entered text, so you couldn't tell what was happening. (Hitting enter would therefore execute whatever had been written at the command prompt at the moment the sub process completed).

After trying a LOT of different approaches, I eventually settled on one that suits my purposes. IMO, the key thing to do to avoid a confusing mess is to first issue a CTRL-C command from the subshell(s) to the main shell (in order to cancel anything that may have been written at the moment the lengthy process completes), and THEN print the notification to terminal.

Here's what it looks like (with `sleep 3` instead of `lengthy_process`):

```
TOPSHELLPID=$$; ( (TEMP=$(sleep 3; echo -e "kill -INT $TOPSHELLPID; echo '\n\n===============\nConsummatum Est\n===============\n'; kill -INT $TOPSHELLPID" ); bash -c "$TEMP") & )
```